# ../npm/bin/npx-cli.js: No such file or directory

Tags: typescript, npm, prettier, react-typescript

## Issue description

I created a new React project using the following command

```bash
npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
```

using node version `v18.15.0`.

Then using steps mentioned in [prettier installations section](https://prettier.io/docs/en/install.html) I tried setting up prettier for my project.

I ran the following commands

```bash
npm install --save-dev --save-exact prettier
```

```bash
echo {}> .prettierrc.json
```

Then I created `.prettierignore` in the root directory and added the below contents to the file

```
# Ignore artifacts:
build
coverage
```

Then I added the `format` script in my `package.json`

```json
"scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "format": "npx prettier . --write"
  }
```

When I proceed to run `npm run format` it gives the following error

```bash
> my-app@0.1.0 format
> npx prettier . --write

<PATH-TO-PARENT-DIRECTORY-OF-PROJECT>/node_modules/.bin/npx: line 1: ../npm/bin/npx-cli.js: No such file or directory
```

One thing to note is that when I try to run other scripts mentioned above, it runs perfectly. I suspect there is some problem with `npx` itself.

## Machine

MacBook Pro 16-inch, 2021, Chip Apple M1 Pro, macOS Venture 13.14.1

Can someone help me get around this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I found out that the parent folder of the project had certain `node_modules` folder present in it. Once I deleted that folder, everything started to work as expected. I do not know why it started working but it did.